# Parse and UIPickerView search

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, uipickerview

I develop an application with parse , I would want to use a filter search with picker view for the user . I have success to populate my UIPickerView with Parse data , now I would want to know how to display the data what the user have choose for example : the user choose blue on the picker view , all the data with key blue was displaying on table view on new view .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to store data with a reference to the key value. For example: "Value1: red" "Value2: blue", etc...
Then you have to select only the corresponding value to the key. I don't know how you store data, but this is the concept. 
Please, explain well next time!

Comment: Yes, I made him(it), I want that the user looks for a restaurant in a city I thus have a key " city ". I succeeded has populate my PickerView with the base(basis) of given but now I do not know how to filter the data plz help

Comment: I just said you: how your data is stored? There are few way to filter it. Post your code